# R - write value into variable after two statements

Tags: r, variables, if-statement, for-loop

I have a for loop with two if statements. it all works fine, except that I would like to add the values passing the second if statement to the variable v1. I assign the variable first and the variable gets filled with a lot of NA's and the three values I am expecting. But I want only those three values in the variable.

So instead of writing only the `i` that fulfills the requirements, every single `i` gets written into the variable.

```
v1 <- c()

for(i in seq_along(y$values)){
  if(y$lengths[i] < 500 && y$values[i] == TRUE){
    y$values[i] <- FALSE
  }
  if(y$lengths[i] > 500 && y$values[i] == TRUE){
    print(y$lengths[i])
    v1[[i]] <- y$lengths[i]
  }
}
```

I had a look at the apply functions, but couldn't really figure out how to use both if statements in apply.

The data is a large logical vector. I use `y <- rle(vec)` on that vector, which gives me `y$lengths` (everything between 1 and a few hundred thousand) and `y$values` (TRUE and FALSE).

The desired result is the rle lengths where >500 and TRUE are true.:

```
[1] 5120
[1] 16630
[1] 10188
```

Which the print command gives me just fine.

`dput(y$length)` gives me:

```
c(129719L, 1L, 79337L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
6L, 1L, 5120L, 1L, 39L, 1L, 12L, 1L, 121L, 1L, 14L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 10L, 2L, 6L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 
1L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 13L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 13L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 9L, 2L, 
6L, 1L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 16630L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 
1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 10L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 12L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 14L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 39L, 1L, 20L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 9L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 
1L, 16L, 1L, 22L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 20L, 1L, 18L, 1L, 20L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 15L, 
1L, 10L, 1L, 40L, 1L, 30L, 1L, 111L, 1L, 314L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 10188L, 
4L, 88L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 15L, 1L, 24L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 16L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 
7L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 16L, 1L, 4071L, 5L, 162912L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 280986L)
```

Comment: Please `dput()` your data and include an example of the desired result

Comment: still confused with your question! you want only those y$lengths which are greater than 500?

Comment: Change `v1[[i]] <- y$lengths[i]` to `v1 <- c(v1, y$lengths[i])`. Or, better `y$lengths[y$lengths>500]`

Comment: @ExperimenteR that did exactly what I wanted. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the final v1 vector very efficiently without loops or apply like this:

```
v1 <- y$lengths[y$lengths > 500 & y$values == TRUE]
```

If you want to use loops here are two options:

(1) You can append to v1 like this:

```
v1 <- c()
for(i in seq_along(y$values)){
  if(y$lengths[i] < 500 && y$values[i] == TRUE){
    y$values[i] <- FALSE
  }
  if(y$lengths[i] > 500 && y$values[i] == TRUE){
    print(y$lengths[i])
    v1 <- c(v1, y$lengths[i])
  }
}
```

(2) Appending like this can get really slow if the vector v1 gets really long. As an alternative you can preallocate then exclude the NAs in the end like this:

```
v1 <- rep(NA, length)
for(i in seq_along(y$values)){
  if(y$lengths[i] < 500 && y$values[i] == TRUE){
    y$values[i] <- FALSE
  }
  if(y$lengths[i] > 500 && y$values[i] == TRUE){
    print(y$lengths[i])
    v1[i] <- y$lengths[i]
  }
}
v1 <- v1[!is.na(v1)]
```

Comment: The version without loops is really nice!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work with the sample data I inferred by reading your question:

```
y<-data.frame(lengths=seq(100,900,100), 
              values=c("TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE"))
v1 <- c()

for(i in seq_along(y$values)){
  if(y$lengths[i] < 500 && y$values[i] == TRUE){
y$values[i] <- FALSE
  }
  if(y$lengths[i] > 500 && y$values[i] == TRUE){
#print(y$lengths[i])
ifelse(length(v1)>0, v1<-rbind(v1, y$lengths[i]), v1<-y$lengths[i])
#v1 <- rbind(y$lengths[i])
  }
}
```

**

```
> v1
   [,1]
v1 700
   900
```

**